# EXCEL: How to program a limit calculation

Tags: excel-formula

For instance, there is a circumstance where X gets payments until it has received  30% of total LTD payments.

So if there were $100 of prior payments to Y, X would get $30.
But then total payments would be $130, so X would receive an additional $9.
But then total payments would be $139, so X would receive an additional $2.7.

etc. etc.

Eventually the additional payments to X would be de minimus.. say the de minimus threshold would be $1.

Any insights as to how I can program this in excel?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the sum of `100+(100*0.3)+((100+(100*0.3))*0.3)+...` ?

Comment: Yes, that would be a 1st step, then I could subtract out prior payments to Y to get the residual amount which should be due to X.

Comment: I think this would be easy if not for the _de minimus_ requirement. It's a geometric series. The formula `X = ( 1/(1-P) - 1) * Y` (where P is the percentage and Y is the prior payments) would give you the answer. However, for your example, that gives 42.85714. I think you are looking for 41.7 instead. Have you considered using VBA?

Comment: Yep, that works.  Thought the de minimus requirement would make it easier, but the pure math is pure :)  Thanks.